# In C#, how to know when external service is done making callbacks?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, callback, service-reference

I have an external reference in my .NET **console application** that does some language translations on large strings for me.

In a loop, I make a bunch of calls to the service. There are probably 5000-8000 calls total.

The service requires that I implement a callback function so that it can give the translated string back to me when the work is completed. In another class which inherits the TranslationService's interface, I have implemented their callback function:

```
class MyTranslationServiceCallback : TranslationService.ITranslationServiceCallback
{
    public void TranslateTextCallback(string sourceContent, string responseContent)
    {
        UpdateMyDatabase(responseContent);
    }
}
```

When debugging, I have added `Console.Readkey` at the very end of my `Main()` to prevent the app from closing so that it can finish getting all of the callbacks. So far, I have just assumed that when it stops entering the callback function for a minute or so that it is "complete" (I know, this is bad).

So it looks like:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        foreach (var item in itemList)
        {
            TranslationService.TranslateText(item.EnglishText, "french");
        }

        Console.Readkey()
    }
}
```

What is the proper way to determine whether or not all the callbacks have been completed?

Comment: Does the translation service not tell the status? If not you can count the calls you made and count the callbacks.

Comment: @Vijayakrishna No, this is an in-house service that is relatively new. The translation service keeps track of nothing and only returns me the source string and translated string in their callback function.

Answer (score 1):

Since translation service does not have any way of telling the status of translations you will need to keep track of the calls made and callbacks. Create a singleton which has a counter and increment with each call. Decrease the count in each call back.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the async framework built into .NET? All you need to do is to fire off tasks and keep track of them in an array, where then you can call `Task.WhenAll` to block the program until all Tasks are complete.

**Note:** I'm using the [Nito.AsyncEx](http://nuget.org/packages/Nito.AsyncEx) NuGet Package, in order to run async code from Console apps.

```
class Program
    {
      static int Main(string[] args)
      {
        return AsynContent.Run(() => MainAsync(args));
      }

      static async Task<int> MainAsync(string[] args)
      {
        var taskList = new List<Task>();

        foreach (var item in itemList)
        {
          Task.Factory.StartNew(() => TranslationService.TranslateText(item.EnglishText, "french");
        }

        Task.WhenAll(taskList.ToArray());
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're implementing this in .NET, then async/await is your friend.

It would be great if, rather than returning the result via callbacks, `TranslationService` returned a `Task<string>`.

Then you could implement the following:

```
static async Task TranslateAllItems(IEnumerable<Item> list)
{
     foreach(var item in itemList)
     {
         string result = await TranslationService.TranslateText(item.EnglishText, "french");
         UpdateMyDatabase(item.EnglishText, content);
     }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Task task = TranslateAllItems(itemList);
    task.Wait();
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

The above solution would perform each translation in sequence, waiting for one translation task to complete before commencing with the next one.

If it would be faster to start all of the translations, then wait for the entire batch to finish:

```
static Task TranslateAllItems(IEnumerable<Item> list)
{
     List<Task> waitingTasks = new List<Task>();
     foreach(var item in itemList)
     {
          string englishText = item.EnglishText;
          var task = TranslationService.TranslateText(englishText , "french")
              .ContinueWith(taskResult => UpdateMyDatabase(englishText, taskResult.Result);
          waitingTasks.Add(task);
     }
     return Task.WhenAll(waitingTasks);
 }
```